# WRF I/O: Can any variable be output into the wrfout file-stream?

Tags: wrf

This question is related to the WRF (Weather Research and Forecasting) Model

I read somewhere that a variable one wants to output, needs to be defined as state variable in the Registry like this (defines the variable QFX, which already is in the output file)

```
state    real  QFX              ij      misc        1         -      rh       "QFX"                   "UPWARD MOISTURE FLUX AT THE SURFACE"          "kg m-2 s-1"
```

where "h" in "rh" stands for "history", i.e. the output in the wrfout_d01_.... NETCDF standard output history files.

**Can I add any variable as state variable?**

For example EETA (transpiration), which is defined in the module_sf_ruclsm. (at the physics layer). [Gill WRF I/O](https://www.climatescience.org.au/sites/default/files/WRF_gill_registry.pdf) states "Local variables inside of physics packages are not controlled by the Registry". So do I need to initialize EETA to the variables in module_surface_driver.F?

I copied the line from QFX and changed the variable name to EETA, but it failed when executing wrf.exe in ./frame/module_domain.F on  line 1174

```
WRITE(mess,*)'W A R N I N G : Unable to modify mask for ',TRIM(lookee),&
             '.  Variable not found. File: ',TRIM(fname),' at line ',lineno
```

**Do I need to edit the namelist to output the variable?**

according to [Gill WRF I/O](https://www.climatescience.org.au/sites/default/files/WRF_gill_registry.pdf) edit &time_control section:

```
iofields_filename = "myoutfields.txt” (MAXDOM) 
io_form_auxhist24 = 2 (choose an available stream) 
auxhist24_interval = 10 (MAXDOM, every 10 minutes)
```

Thanks